# How to update a seaborn line plot with ipywidgets checkboxes?

Tags: python, checkbox, seaborn, interactive, ipywidgets

I am struggling with the ipywidgets module.

I am trying to make a plot where you can toggle lines off/on with checkboxes based on a province.

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
sns.lineplot(data=df5, x="Date_of_report", y="Total_reported", hue="Province", ax=ax)
provinces = df5["Province"].unique()
chk = [widgets.Checkbox(description=a) for a in provinces]
def updatePlot(**kwargs):
    print([(k,v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])

widgets.interact(updatePlot, **{c.description: c.value for c in chk})
```

As you can see, I can draw the checkboxes and it prints out the status of the boxes.
but I don't know how to update the seaborn line plot. So when you select say: Drenthe it only shows the line from Drenthe.

[image]

here is the dataframe as a dict:

{'Date_of_report': {0: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2020-03-13 10:00:00')}, 'Province': {0: 'Drenthe', 1: 'Flevoland', 2: 'Friesland', 3: 'Gelderland', 4: 'Groningen', 5: 'Limburg', 6: 'Noord-Brabant', 7: 'Noord-Holland', 8: 'Overijssel', 9: 'Utrecht'}, 'Total_reported': {0: 14, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 64, 4: 4, 5: 71, 6: 377, 7: 66, 8: 18, 9: 83}, 'Hospital_admission': {0: 0, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 9, 4: 1, 5: 17, 6: 65, 7: 4, 8: 0, 9: 7}, 'Deceased': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 3, 6: 5, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}}

Comment: Can you mock up a dataframe from a dictionary so I can run your code?

Comment: i have updated the question